# How to get input from xml laravel

Tags: xml, laravel

I am newbie in laravel. now, I make a API which get input from a xml. 
I confused, how can I get the input which be given?
I try using Input::all(), but I get an Array with index \nMY XML

so, I want the input can be format to array or json without string processing, but automatic convert, maybe using library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, at least I use php://input to get xml

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get converted xml from your incoming request in the same way you would with a json or form reqest, this package makes it possible:

https://github.com/mtownsend5512/request-xml